# Step up converters DC or AC?

Tags: transformer, converter

The wikipedia article on Step up converters says

> A boost converter (step-up converter) is a **DC-to-DC** power converter with an output voltage greater than its input voltage.

However if I look at [any given step up converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0022QOSDK) it will mention that the input and output is AC. Why this discrepancy? I hope and guess it's just a terminology thing, but the concept of an AC step-up converter is something I have a lot of trouble understanding, so I would like to have my terminology right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link is for a Step-Up [transformer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer). Relying on coupled magnetic flux, a transformer can only convert AC.

A [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) converter is typically a DC-DC step-up converter.

A Boost converter can be used in DC-AC conversion typically called an [Inverter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_inverter); where a DC voltage is Boosted to a higher DC voltage and converted to AC.

A Boost converter is also an important component in a [PFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor#Power_factor_correction_.28PFC.29_in_non-linear_loads) (Power Factor Correction) circuit.

Comment: That's so obvious in hindsight. For reasons that are beyond me I was reading the terms transformer and converter as synonyms despite knowing better. Especially things like how the amazon caption both mentions transformer and converter did confuse me a lot though. Thanks!